# recompiling database.yml file with gemfile? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gemfile, pg

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and postgreSQL and had a question. Does the database.yml file get compiled when you run `bundle install` on a Gemfile? Initially my gemfile had sqlite3, but I changed it to pg and tried to run `bundle install` again to recompile the database.yml file, but the file still says it's using SQLite.

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

I want the adapter to be switched to `postgresql` and I believe some other fields should be switched when using pg, but I'm unsure. Can anyone clarify this for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `database.yml` is not recompiled automatically. When you change the gem in `Gemfile`, you need to also change the file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dbname
  username: user
  password: password
  encoding: unicode
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace too your the adapter value in your `config/database.yml`

When you run `bundle install` it will install the gems declared in your `Gemfile`, but you must manually setup you database configuration. Bundle don't compile your anything on your application except the `Gemfile.lock` where are declared the gems versions.

Something like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  host: localhost
  password: password # if you need a password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  host: localhost
  password: password # if you need a password

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_production
  host: localhost
  password: password # probably you will need a password
```